# Finding warmest and coldest temperatures

Tags: linear-algebra, maxima-minima

A penguin is walking on an ice ball of radius 1 m centered at the origin.

Let $T$ be the temperature at a point $(x,y,z)$ on the sphere and it is given by $T(x,y,z) = x^2 +4y^2 +9z^2 +4xy +6xz +12yz$ °F.

What are the warmest and coldest temperatures that the penguin encounters?

I found the eigenvector of the quadratic form and I do not know how to go on to the next step.

Comment: Take some derivatives, set to zero.  Alternately, complete some squares.  What happens?

Comment: i just made it to a quadratic form.

Comment: Then you should show that.  It makes it much easier to give an helpful answer to know where you are stuck and what you do not understand.  It also shows you are not just trying to get an answer to a homework problem you have not invested any thought in.  It also saves others from reproducing your work.

Comment: i found eigenvector of quadratic form and idk how to go on to next step.

Comment: Penguin is going to slide off that ball if it wanders too far from the top, so there are large parts of the ball penguin will never encounter. This seems to me to be a problem in avain anatomy as much as mathematics. Maybe post it to seabirds.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- For a positive semidefinite matrix, $v^TAv \geq 0$, hence if you can attain this value, you have obtain the smallest value.
- Also prove  that we have $v^TAv$  to be at most the largest eigenvalue where $v^Tv=1$.

To see this, consider the langrangian $v^TAv-\lambda (v^Tv-1)$ and differentiate it and equate it to  $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues and quadratic forms only complicate the matter here.

Since $T(x,y,z)=(x+2y+3z)^2$, the coldest parts of the sphere are where $x+2y+3z=0$; $T$ is 0 °F at these points. Likewise, the warmest parts are the points of tangency of the sphere and planes parallel to $x+2y+3z=0$ – where the line defined by the vector $(1,2,3)$ intersects the sphere. These points are $\frac{(1,2,3)}{\Vert1,2,3\Vert}=\frac1{\sqrt{14}}(1,2,3)$ and its negation; $T$ is 14 °F.